# React Router: The Router only loads / path and does not load any other path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I am trying to load paths from react-router-dom using the Route but it is only fetching the "/" path, It does not load any other path, the authentication logic was working fine before but with routing nothing seems to be working, If I add any other component to "/" path it will start to load but if I remove "/" and add any other path for instance "/auth" it will display a blank white screen. I have tried a number of ways but couldn't find any solution,
I have added the right component they were working smoothly before I added routing, now I am a beginner and it might an easy fix for you guys, Please help me out here because I am stuck ad can't find any solutions. I hope my question is clear.

App.js

```js
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

import Auth from './Components/Auth/Auth';

import Home from './Pages/Home';

import { AuthContext } from './Context/auth-context';
import {Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './Pages/About';



const  App = props => {

  const authenticated = useContext(AuthContext).auth;

  let routes = (
    <Switch>
    <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
    <Route path= "/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Redirect to="/"/>
    </Switch>
   );
  
  if(authenticated){

    routes = (
      <Switch>
      <Route path= '/about' component={About}/>
      <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
      <Route path= '/' exact component={Home}/>
      <Redirect to='/'/>
      </Switch>
    )

  }

  return (
    <div>
      {routes}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import ContextProvider from './Context/auth-context';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ContextProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </ContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use exact path for "/" route. In your code the routes contain "exact" keyword, but misplaced

```
      let routes = (
        <Switch>
        <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
        <Route exact path= "/" component={Home}/>
        <Redirect to="/"/>
        </Switch>
       );
      
      if(authenticated){

        routes = (
          <Switch>
          <Route path= '/about' component={About}/>
          <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
          <Route exact path= '/' component={Home}/>
          <Redirect to='/'/>
          </Switch>
        )

      }
```

Comment: The order of properties doesn't matter. `<Route exact path="/"...` is the same as `<Route path="/" exact...`.

Comment: The code you posted is *not* a runnable snippet (just click the "Run..." button and you will realize that)! Please edit your answer and format your code as a **plain code block** instead (use simple, three back-tick code fences).

Comment: Never used the "exact" property that way. didn't know.

Comment: Hello there I tried your method but didn't work, I came up with a solution kindly look it through and please tell me if it goes against the convention and will it cause any future bugs? I'll be grateful, [link] (https://imgur.com/VMlhmQb)

Comment: as you can see in the code picture I am replace the root... "/" route before and after authentication, can it cause any bugs in the future

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you use Redirect is right there. I don't know how to fix your code but why don't you try that, maybe it will help:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import ....
.....
const  App = props => {
const authenticated = useContext(AuthContext).auth;
return (
<Router>
  <Route
     exact
     path="/auth"
     component={Auth}
  />

  <Route
     exact
     path="/"
     render={(props) =>(!authenticated ? <Redirect to={'/auth'}/> 
     : 
     <Home authenticated={authenticated} {...props} />)}
  />
   <Route
      exact
      path="/about"
      render={(props) => (!authenticated ? <Redirect to={'/auth'} 
      /> : 
      <About authenticated={authenticated} {...props} />)}
  />
 
</Router> 
)}
```

Comment: Hello there I tried your method but didn't work, I came up with a solution kindly look it through and please tell me if it goes against the convention and will it cause any future bugs? I'll be grateful, [link] (https://imgur.com/VMlhmQb)

Comment: as you can see in the code picture I am replace the root... "/" route before and after authentication, can it cause any bugs in the future

Comment: So I understand your logic is: !authenticated => only show (/auth) route. Authenticated is true => showing Home, About page and hide Auth page. 
If it is your purpose, ur code looks fine.

Comment: I edit my solution after knowing exactly your logic. I think your method is fine but if you try mine, let me know if it works. thanks!